# Getting Selected Item from the Data Table

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a data table which consists of the number of columns. Some of them are **v-text-field** and **v-select**
When I select a value from the drop-down that is my v-select the value is not appearing in this.selected which is an array selected:[]

What I did is like this:-

```
 <v-data-table
   v-model="selected"
   v-bind:headers="headers"
   v-bind:items="Data"
   select-all
   v-bind:search="search"
   v-bind:pagination.sync="pagination"              
   class="elevation-1"
          >
```

I have a button called save and on click, I want to save the values but the selected values and not all Data values

I tried to print `console.log(this.selected);` but it gives me empty array and not selected values of the table

when I do like following it is automatically selecting all entry for all the drop down, when I select only one entry

```
    <v-data-table 
   v-bind:headers="headers"
   v-bind:items="Data"
   select-all
   v-bind:search="search"
   v-bind:pagination.sync="pagination"              
   class="elevation-1"
          >
```

and

```
<td class="text-xs-left">
  <v-select
   v-bind:items="name" 
    v-model="selected"                          
    label="Select"                              
    single-line
      bottom>
   </v-select>
```

Comment: Can you post a pen here? https://codepen.io/johnjleider/pen/bgJOrX It will help to see the data along with the table.